# How do you cope with the task of adding hierarchy to the navigation menu?

Tags: menus, hierarchical

Say we got a theme with a horizontal menu that shows only the top-level pages.

How do you manage with the task to make the menu hierarchical, adding subpages?

Any appropriate plugins for that?

If you use custom css for that and you're not good enough for writing it yourself, where do you look for sample scripts?

Dynamicdrive.com is one place I found some stuff, but not too much.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the new default theme for Wordpress 3, it fully supports custom drop down menu's right in the admin panel under apperance->menu's.  Depending on the theme you are using it should support submenu's by defualt.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that functionality, but I'm interested in the cases theme does not support submenus.

Comment: answer still stands,  look at how those theme's do it and convert it into your theme.  some php/css/xhtml knowledge would probably be required